# How to keep a Kubernetes pod running when main process is not blocking?

Tags: docker, process, kubernetes, blocking, postfix-mta

I have a postfix pod that I want to keep running for as long as I have my whole cluster up. The problem is that the "start" command:

`postfix start`

is non-blocking, meaning it exits as soon as it successfully fires off the command. As far as I know, this is the only way to start postfix.

The way Docker works is that it will exit the container as soon as the main process exits. So, when `postfix start` returns, Docker will assume the whole container is finished doing its thing and close it, even though this command fired off other processes.

How do I prevent this from happening? The only workaround I can think of is `postfix start && sleep infinity` but this seems hacky and weird. I'd like to avoid a sleep infinity if possible. Is there an alternative way to start postfix that is blocking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom CMD script that keeps staying in foreground after the `postfix start` command.

For instance, you can use this one, took from [here](https://github.com/container-images/postfix/blob/master/files/start.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wait before postfix is really started.

function get_state {
    echo $(script -c 'postfix status' | grep postfix/postfix-script)
}

postfix start
echo $(get_state)

while true; do
    state=$(get_state)
    if [[ "$state" != "${state/is running/}" ]]; then
        PID=${state//[^0-9]/}
        if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        if [[ ! -d "/proc/$PID" ]]; then
            echo "Postfix proces $PID does not exist."
            break
        fi
    else
        echo "Postfix is not running."
        break
    fi
done
```

This script keeps running a while loop until the postfix process is up, and it exits when the process exits. This way you'll have your container correctly stop if postfix dies for any reason.

Comment: for your consideration, that will positively burn CPU time; a concession would be `while sleep 1; do ...`

Comment: Yes I agree. I just posted a random script from a similar use case to share the general idea

Answer (score 0):

Since [Postfix 3.3 (2018)](http://www.postfix.org/announcements/postfix-3.3.0.html), you can run postfix in the foreground (blocking). You could use command:

`postfix startfg`

More about dockerizing postfix [here](https://xc2.wb1.xyz/post/how-to-run-a-postfix-mail-server-in-a-docker-container/) (answer also extracted from that link).